# Scan a matrix and find the maximum value in Matlab between 2 ranges

Tags: matlab, matrix, range, minimum, threshold

I have a matrix in the form of a text file, I was hoping  to scan it using MATLAB, and scan for the maximum value in between 2 points (1.5 and 2) and use that as a threshold.

I wrote a code but it rerturned an error.

```
    [filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*txt', 'Pick text file');
data = dlmread(fullfile(pathname, filename)); 
t=data(:,1);
N = size(t,1);
m= max(data(1.5,2));
figure;
threshold = m;
```

Error in file (line 214)
m= max(data(1.5,2));

Comment: You are currently asking it to find a value using 1.5 as an index, which isn't possible. I'd recommend reading the matlab help on logical operators.

Comment: @etmuse I know the data range which is between 1.5 and 2 so was hoping to scan the data and find the maximum values and use it as threshold

Comment: As stated: you're using `1.5` as *index*, `data(A,B)` gives you the value of `data` on the indices as given by `A,B`. MATLAB requires your indices to be nonnegative, real integers. Use logical operators to define your range of `[1.5 2]`, then use `max` on the resulting set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data(1.5,2)` does not ask for elements of `data` with values between `1.5` and `2`; it asks for the element of `data` on the "1.5th" row and 2nd column, which is clearly undefined. Indices have to be integers.

The elements of `data` with values between `1.5` and `2` can be obtained with

```
data(data > 1.5 & data < 2)
```

so you can get the largest of these using

```
m = max(data(data > 1.5 & data < 2));
```